# How to see debugging massages from multiple different namespaces

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm using the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) npm package

I need to be able to see debugging massages from multiple namespaces, for instance: both the massages from `app:startup` and both from `app:db`.

The problem that I'm getting only one related namespace each time.

### Example:

app.js:

```
const startupDebug = require('debug')('app:startup');
const dbDebug = require('debug')('app:db');

startupDebug("some app:startup related massage");
dbDebug("some app:db related massage");
```

terminal:

```
export DEBUG=app:startup
```

Result:

```
some app:startup related massage
```

### Desired Output:

```
some app:startup related massage
some app:db related massage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved:

To see the related debugging massages only for `app:startup` and `app:db` we can just separate each of the namespaces by comma `,` terminal:

```
export DEBUG=app:startup,app:db
```

To see all debugging massages we can use the asterisk `*`, terminal:

```
export DEBUG=app:*
```